# what is space the light calculating belong to in opengl?

Tags: opengl, glsl

last week,i've saw one shader script,which does deferred shading .but i was confused by some transform the vertex shader does.such as the following:

vert:

```
varying vec3 normals;
varying vec4 position;
uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 WorldMatrix;

void main( void )
{
    // Move the normals back from the camera space to the world space
    mat3 worldRotationInverse = transpose(mat3(WorldMatrix));

    gl_Position     = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0]  = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    **normals           = normalize(worldRotationInverse * gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);         <<<<<**
    position        = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_FrontColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

frag :

```
varying vec4        position;
varying vec3        normals;
varying mat4        TBN;
uniform sampler2D   tDiffuse;

void main( void )
{
    gl_FragData[0]      = vec4(texture2D(tDiffuse,gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb, 0);
    gl_FragData[1]      = vec4(position.xyz,0);
    gl_FragData[2]      = vec4(normals.xyz,0);
}
```

i really don't understand why transform the normal to world space(modelspace).beacause the reason that my think  is the normal in eyespace(cameraspace) can at least eliminate invisible vertices,and even ploygon. i don't know whether i understand something wrong or not.

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lighting can be done in any pre-projection space (e.g., world coordinates or eye coordinates), as long as all the objects and lights are all in that same space.

This shader does lighting in eye coordinates - you can tell by the use of the legacy `gl_NormalMatrix` implicit uniform variable.  This approach mimics what was done in the legacy OpenGL pipeline where lighting (done by the OpenGL implementation when there weren't shaders) was done in eye coordinates.  There's nothing wrong with doing lighting in eye coordinates, it's just not quite as intuitive as other spaces.

More modern approaches do lighting in world coordinates and don't require the use of the normal transform matrix (which is the inverse transpose of the upper 3x3 of the current model-view matrix).

Comment: You still need to tranform normals from model space into world space if doing illumination calculations in world space. No matter how you turn it, you'll not get around transforming the normals. also the modern approach is doing illumination calculations in view/eye/camera space, especially with deferred shading, as this eliminates the need for an additional bitplane in the geometry buffer (you can save the Z), because the back projection becomes simpler.

Comment: hi! @radical7,@datenwolf .   as far as i know, opengl has no concept such as world space. how could it do that?     // Move the normals back from the camera space to the world space
    **mat3 worldRotationInverse = transpose(mat3(WorldMatrix));
    normals     = normalize(worldRotationInverse * gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal**

Comment: @haohaochao: You're using shaders; OpenGL doesn't have the concept of any space before [*clip space*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Clipping). *You* define the concepts that *you* want to use.